# What command line software should I use to render justified text to fit into a given rectangular box?

Tags: text

I would like to render justified text onto a transparent background, and save the result as png. It is important that the text should fit in a predefined rectangular box, and possibly fill it in, by automatically setting the font size and/or line and character spacing.

Which command line software should I use for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for ImageMagick – which usually even ships with the standard repositories of most Linux distributions. Your requirement is e.g. [detailed here](https://www.metricrat.co.uk/imagemagick/im-tips-and-tricks-part-iv#h.442xzwhz6z9k):

```
convert -size 300 -font Ubuntu -border 10 -bordercolor White -define pango:justify=true pango:"$(cat ./lorem.txt)" pango_justify.gif
```

They use GIF, but PNG (and many other formats) are supported as well. [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) is *the* command-line tool when it comes to manipulating graphic files. There are many tutorials out there for it, too.

The package name to install it usually is `imagemagick`.

Comment: Very good, from a script I can try different fontsizes while examining the resulting image height, so the script can choose the most appropriate one.

Comment: How can I achieve automatic hyphenation by defining the language of the text, or by setting the possible hyphenation points in some way?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with how-tos on the topic (and asking that here would be off-topic anyhow). Shouldn't be too hard to find tutorials for, though, now that you know the right terms.

Comment: Yes, now I have found: you have to put '&#173;' symbols into the text, at hyphenation points. And use a library, eg Ruby gem to hyphenate the text.